# repair windows boot loader after cloning to SSD

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, bootloader

I bought my PC with Windows 10 on it, later installing Ubuntu for dual-booting. Recently, I wanted to replace the HDD inside with an SSD of the same size, so I copied all the partitions to the SSD (GPT partitioning) using GParted and installed the SSD in the laptop.

On startup, GRUB is loaded and I can:

- Boot Ubuntu normally
- Select the "Windows Boot Manager on `/boot/sda1` or select `bootmgfw.efi` manually, however it loads a Recovery BSOD, stating the following with options to access the recovery environment (`F1`) or boot parameters (`F8`) but those don't work (same screen):

  ```
  File: \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi is missing or broken
  Error code: 0xc000000e
  ```

As I understand it, Windows Boot Manager is loaded but cannot find the Windows boot loader (probably because not looking into the right partition), so what I need to do is give the right partition to the boot loader, but I have no idea how to do that.

How do I fix this, preferably something that can be done from Linux and doesn't involve a reinstall of Windows?

Comment: What is your Linux?

Comment: Ubuntu (but anything that can be used from a live usb will do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked only because I had kept the old hard drive, but at least solved my problem.

I [created a Clonezilla Live USB](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php), and followed [their instructions](https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone) to perform disk-to-disk cloning from the old HDD to the new SSD. It all worked fine and I was able to boot on Windows as well as Ubuntu right after cloning.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install -y boot-repair
sudo boot-repair
```

Open the Boot Repair application and select *Advanced Options > Other Options tab - Repair Windows boot files*. The boot flag should be placed on the same partition on which Ubuntu is installed.

[image]

Comment: I tried it but still the same blue screen. For some reason I don't have the option "place the boot flag on", but I added the boot flag on the efi fat32 partition with GParted

Comment: Does your computer use EFI, and is the disk formatted as MBR or GPT? Do you have a Windows installation media?

Comment: The disk is formatted as GPT, I'm not sure about EFI but I have an option about UEFI in the GRUB booting menu. I don't have a Windows installation media (I tried to create one but it didn't work, I might retry).

Comment: Try perhaps [Rescatux](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/). You can create it from Linux.

Comment: I tried the following options from Rescatux, unsuccessfully:
File system check:
- sda1 (windows efi): OK
- sda2 (windows reserved partition 16 Mo, no filesystem): ERROR filesystem check with automatic fix failed
- sda3 (windows OS): OK
- sda4 (recovery, I guess? ntfs 875Mo): OK
Reinstall Microsoft Windows UEFI: 
- WARNING: backup of EFI directory went wrong
- ERROR: the reinstallation of Windows UEFI boot entries went wrong

Comment: complete logs for the filesystem check of sda2 say `the superblock could not be rad or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem`

Comment: @harrymc I wasn't aware `BootRec` will cause [issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68581/246705) with GRUB and I've edited your answer with a whitespace so I can switch my downvote to an upvote

Comment: @JW0914: Thank you.