# Selected boot device failed. Press any key to reboot the system

Tags: ubuntu, window, dualboot

I tried dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows 10, however the GRUB menu wasn’t loading, presumably because I have Alienware OS which interferes with it, so I ran:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

- Now my computer won’t boot either OS normally on UEFI. I switched the booting mode from UEFI to Legacy, which let me boot an old version of Ubuntu I had installed previously.
- I tried using the method that was given in a comment and it seems I'm getting an error when trying to use `sudo`: 
   [image: Here is the error that I got when I tried to sudo add]

How can I reverse that command using the Linux terminal?

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/a/1624974/529800) answer may help

Comment: @JW0914 Thank you for the help but when I tried to run each command, I ran into some errors.

404 Not Found IP

Comment: Please add the terminal error output to your question (it does require internet access), as this has to be fixed from Linux (doing so from Windows will destroy GRUB boot). CSM [legacy] boot mode should not be used, as its only purpose was to allow distro installs that didn't support EFI boot pre-2017ish _(i.e. all distros now support EFI boot, so CSM [legacy] mode should remain disabled - UEFI is 64bit, CSM mode emulates BIOS' 16bit architecture via 32bit, resulting in booting going from ~10s to ~45s)_ If an OS was installed w/ CSM mode disabled, it will generally not boot w/ CSM mode enabled.

Comment: @JW0914 Got it. Just added the terminal error output in my description.

Comment: Use a search engine to google the [error](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ubuntu+the+repository+no+longer+has+a+release+file)