# I have a dual drive hard disk(SSD+ HDD) and my ubuntu is installed on SSD, can I install windows on the HDD?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning, hybrid-storage

I have a dual drive disk(SSD+ HDD) and my ubuntu(20.04) is installed on SSD, I've been trying to install windows 10 on the HDD (I made two partitions, and left 1TB unallocated), but everytime, windows get installed unsuccessfully

I installed windows with making a Bootable USB with rufus and booted into it, and in the step of partitioning I used the 2TB HDD which i had formated GPT in ubuntu disks program, and separated a 460GB and a 540 and installed windows on the 420GB one, (I left 1 tb unallocated) (windows made a MSR partition itself too)
after installation of windows 10 and booting the OS for the first time,  after getting services ready, it spends a long time on getting ready and then it goes to a blue screen saying a required device isn't connected or can't be accessed with error 0xc000000e.

I tried solutions on the internet but the auto repair says that it couldn't repair the OS and when I type `bootrec /scanos` it says found 0 Windows installed

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Am I doing anything wrong?" - evidently you do. But if you want help, much more information is required about your setup and how exactly you're installing Windows.

Comment: @harrymc edited

Comment: Is the computer on BIOS or EFI? When booting, do you boot directly into Windows or Grub?

Comment: Yes, you can dual boot Windows and Ubuntu _(don't use `BootRec` as it will result in GRUB being unbootable, instead use [this](https://superuser.com/a/1624974/529800))_. All OSes should use the same EFI partition, so ensure Ubuntu set the GUID of the EFI partition as `c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b` _(multiple EFI boot partitions aren't really recommended or required)_. If there's no data on the HDD you're installing Windows to, wipe the partition table via the Windows install USB _(last step in GUI)_, as Windows requires specific GUIDs for the WinRE, EFI, MSR, and normal data partitions

Comment: @harrymc UEFI, Windows

Comment: @JW0914 thanks a world, I just did the thing you gave the link in the other question, and it fixed it easily :) perhaps you will add it as an answer so i can accept it if you want?

Comment: Nice answer @JW0914 ... I just learned a new trick! :)  .. I have been HOSING my grub with bcd .. then fixing grub.. what a PAIN!! :) THANKS!!

Comment: That's not my answer, it's @harrymc's

Comment: @JW0914: In that case, this post is a duplicate.